# Why does tag-highlighting fail for c++?

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

At StackOverflow I use some Interesting Tags. One of those is `c++`. But [questions tagged `c++`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) do not show up highlighted. Only those with another interesting tag do.
What's up?

Comment: I'm glad I'm not going crazy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one was interesting - it will be fixed in the next deployment.  Let's just say that I need to go back and read Joels article:  http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: It's deployed to meta right now - we only deploy stack overflow in the evenings unless it's really urgent.

Comment: It's happening to me now...c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc aren't highlit.

Comment: now they're back! Yay!

Answer (score 10):

Same for me and also for:

- `[c++0x]`, `[visual-c++]`, `[objective-c++]`, `[g++]`, ...
- `[c#]`, ...
- `[java1.4]`, ...

This not only occurs for highlighting, but also for [ignoring](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60649/how-to-ignore-c-questions).

Those worked before, so apparently there is a bug regarding `#`, `+`, `.` with the client-side JavaScript, as those divs don't get the correct class (e.g. `question-summary tagged-interesting`).
<sub>(with my limited web-dev-fu it looks like the client-side `function getTagsSelector(d)` *might* be the culprit)</sub>

Comment: yep new bug. Geoff will fix it tomorrow. THE WHEEL O' BLAME GOES ROUND AND ROUND.. a winner every time!

Comment: @Jeff, can you also fix the weird bug that happens the day after March 31th every year that seem to affect gravitars?  Thanks. (Yes I know)

Answer (score 3):

This is happening again this morning.

Comment: Another JS minification task was added to the build without the proper encoding.  This is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I believe we are currently having a related bug on RPG.

- [Ignoring tags doesn't seem to be working](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/771/ignoring-tags-doesnt-seem-to-be-working)

Comment: Another JS minification task was added to the build without the proper encoding.  This is now fixed.

Answer (score 1):

And it's happening once again across all SE sites.

Comment: Already fixed? Works for me.

Comment: Nope, I have C# as a tag as well as .NET and no C# nor .NET questions are being highlighted.  Wait, nevermind.  Had to un-script-block netdna-cdn.com for it to work.  Is this recent?

Comment: I see some missing highlights as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23

Comment: Apparently it *is* rececnt: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110690/sstatic-net-malware-warning/110692#110692