# Interesting Tag Highlighting Broken for [c++]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-watching, tag-highlighting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does tag-highlighting fail for c++?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60646/why-does-tag-highlighting-fail-for-c)

If you have [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) as a favorite tag, questions with that tag are not longer highlighted in the questions list. They appear as if they wouldn't have any interesting tags.

Comment: It seems to be broken for a lot of tags, I hardly have any questions highlighted on my page now, though I can see almost all questions have tags that I've marked as interesting.

Comment: Just noticed the same for `c#`.

Comment: c++ is broken for me too. I'm sure it used to work not too long ago...

Comment: This broke before the same way: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60646/why-does-tag-highlighting-fail-for-c

Comment: also broken  for .net, but not for php or linq*

Comment: I seem to have the opposite problem with ignored tags, as well... c# and .net are two of those...

Comment: Seems to be fixed now.

Comment: How can it be a duplicate of an issue that was fixed months ago?

Comment: @Kop - regressions, regressions, regressions...

Comment: @Oded: a regression is a new bug and has to be reported, so it shouldn't be a duplicate of the old bug marked as fixed. With that reasoning we shouldn't bother reporting bug that were already reported and marked as fixed. In your bug tracker (which is what meta SO basically is) you either re-open the old bug, something we cannot do, or enter a new one.