# 'Interesting Tag' question highlighting is patchy

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-watching

Seems very 'dupey' - but if I click through to look at questions for my interesting tags, the highlighting is patchy to non-existent.

Stack Overflow, Safari or Firefox, Mac OS X.

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71623/interesting-tag-highlighting-broken-for-c-closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that we no longer highlight the foo tag when you are visiting the `/questions/tagged/foo` page, because we feel it's.. redundant.

Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: yes!  Hadn't noticed before, makes good sense to me - you can see the intersection with other interesting tags.