# Tag highlighting not working for c# only

Tags: bug, status-norepro, tags

This appears to be a repeat bug of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60646/why-does-tag-highlighting-fail-for-c).
But I only suffer from it in chromium in the office.
It works fine on google chrome at home.

Is anyone experiencing something similar?

Comment: Confirmed that it affects my normal (c#) as well as C++.  So exact same symptoms as the previously reported one.  Running chromium 23.0.1241.0 (152481)

Comment: Might help: [Which browsers are officially supported? And what else do I need?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56161/which-browsers-are-officially-supported-and-what-else-do-i-need)

Comment: I hear you, but it _used_ to work with chromium.  Back to IE I guess in the office then, thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it used to work with a previous version of Chromium? And why IE and not Chrome (just curious)?

Comment: Trying to guess why the security team allow one product but disallow the other is futile.  If I had to guess, I suspect it has to do with the autoupdate and data reporting stuff in chrome.

Comment: @Skliwz since this is actually a request to support a currently unsupported browser, think it better get tagged as declined?